# Children of 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' cannot be null. Object derived from UIElement expected

Tags: wpf, exception, uielement

I got this exception and don't know what to do with it.
I'm using a `TreeListView` that I found on the net:

```
  <tv:TreeListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeRoot}" Margin="5"      Width="640" Height="732">

    </tv:TreeListView>
```

Has anyone had this exception?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `TreeRoot` collection in your `DataContext` contains null items.